# Conditional formatting when comparing two rows

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two rows of data for several products: Sales, and Sales Goal. I want to compare each instance of Sales to its Goal, and highlight the cells that did not meet the Goal. Currently I would have to apply a new rule for each cell manually. Is there any way to apply this to the entire table?

[image: Table without formatting]

This is what I would like the table to look like.

[image: Table with goal formatting]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Select the first month and apply conditional formatting when it's less than its goal. Note that the address does not contain the `$` sign. You have to manually type in the address of the goal cell (`B3` in this example):

[image: Format the first month]

Select **Conditional Formatting** on the toolbar, then **Manage Rules...**. Change **Applies to** to cover all the months:

[image: Format the remaining month]

Result:

[image: Final result]

Comment: So I have to compare each value to a specific cell? There is no way to compare the sales row with the value below it in the goal row? Thank you for your answer

Comment: You set it up once and propagate that setting to all the months. Wasn't that you wanted to highlight all months where sales is below the goal?

Comment: The method you have suggested references the same goal cell. I want to have each monthly sales measured against a different goal cell. I have different goals for each month, so I need the sales goal to check each specific monthly goal, not just one goal.

Comment: Try it. It references the monthly goal. You can test that by changing the goal for March to 300 and see the red background disappear

Comment: Using your example, I want my goals to be cells B3:D3. Your method checks every months sales against cell B3.

Comment: I fixed it, you were right! I had quotations on the goal cell, thank you so much.